# c# Windows 8 custom TextBox

Tags: c#, xaml, custom-controls

I'm developping a Windows Store 8 Application. For this I would like some custom TextBox controls. How can I make something like in the picture? (XAML) specifically those corners

[image: Custom TextBox]

Comment: you can make a usercontrol wherein theres an image(the green arrow) and a text box above on it..

Comment: Yes i thought to do it like this, but is it an appropriate way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just make yourself a [custom Control Template](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc189093%28v=vs.95%29.aspx) (Yes the link says Silverlight, but you wont see much difference in the win8 XAML etc) and you could use a `Path` for your backgrounds and even add things like color changing for the different MouseOver, Focused, States etc.

```
<Path Data="M130.32379,0 L142.74992,0 L157.743,15.01704 L142.73584,30.000004 L130.30968,30.000004 L0.31890577,29.99987 L15.159052,15.183544 L0,0.00013974622 z" 
      Fill="#FF1FCD99" Height="30" Width="150" Stretch="Fill" UseLayoutRounding="False"/>
```

Once you have your custom Control Template for your `TextBox` TargetType it's just a matter of applying it where needed with a `Style` tag pointing to your resource like `Style="{StaticResource BlahTextBox}"`.

Hope this helps.